# How to conditionally call click method inside a mat-row in Angular?

Tags: angular

I want to conditionally call click method inside a mat row . I want to call click method only when index value is not 0 , means except the first row .

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay;" class="table-element-row"
                    [class.table-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element" 
                    (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element ; onClick(element.Id , element.Id2)">
                </mat-row>
```

I tried with -

```
<mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay; let i = index;" class="table-element-row"
                    [class.table-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element" 
                    (click)="i!=0 && expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element ; i!=0 && onClickOfRow(element.Id , element.Id2)">
                </mat-row>
```

But that didn't give the result . Can anyone help me on this ?

Comment: Try `i!=0 ? onClickOfRow(element.Id , element.Id2) : null`, or for more readability pass the index to method and add if check in function.

Comment: I tried passing to a function , and console.log(i) , but that is coming as undefined . ANy idea why ?

Comment: Ah I forget, You have to use `let i=dataIndex` when used `multiTemplateDataRows`, BTW the code you posted will also work, just change `index` to `dataIndex` [Angular Material Doc Link](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#multiple-row-templates)